# count multiple colmns and true results only mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, group-by, count, sum

I'm new to mongodb and I've been trying to figure this out but I haven't so far. I think I'm close. I have records similar to this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfdf4385a37e507cff0ff62"),
    "Search_word" : "job01",
    "hadoop" : 0,
    "hive" : 0,
    "javascript" : 0,
    "mongodb" : 0,
    "sql" : 1,
    "java" : 0,
    "sas" : 0,
    "powerbi" : 0,
    "python" : 1,
    "pig" : 0,
    "scala" : 0
}
```

I'm trying to create groups by search word and count the 1s in all the other values. Ive never used mongodb before.

The end result would look like this

```
job01, sql : 100, hive: 205, etc...
job02, sql : 121, hive 10, etc...
```

In python its literally like this

> skill_data = df.groupby(by='Search_word').sum()

I tried doing something like this just to get sql count where it is 1

> db.data_final.aggregate(
> {"$group" :
> {_id : {Search_word:"$Search_word", sql: {"$eq":["$sql",1]} }, count : { $sum : 1} } } )

but it gives me 2 counts one for false where sql not equal 1 and a count that I want for sql that is 1. how can I get rid of the false ? This is what I get now:

> { "_id" : { "Search_word" : "job01", "sql" : true }, "count" : 124 } // this is what i want only and do it for all other values in one query
>
> { "_id" : { "Search_word" : "job01", "sql" : false}, "count" : 279 }

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not getting it clear, if you have only one record in the collection which happens to be the example you provided what will be the expected result in JSON format?

Comment: No I have multiple records of Search_word: job01 each with different 0 and 1 values for the programming skills. I have thousands of records. I just posted one record.

Comment: Maybe you could try this: `db.collection.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$Search_word", sql: {$sum: "$sql"}}});`.

Comment: Do every field always contain just either 1 or 0 as a value? Otherwise I think you'll need a projection to first catch those fields whose value is equal to 1 and then apply a grouping.

Comment: yes all the values of the programming skills are either 0 or 1. I just want a count for the 1s grouped by search word like this [link](https://i.imgur.com/wpvXa2e.png) . my query above works but it gets 2 records 1 true and 1 false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this since the value of each field is either 0 or 1.

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$Search_word", sql: {$sum: "$sql"}}});
```